# How to write text on the top and side of a matrix environment!

Tags: matrices

How do I write a text on the top (saying Dimensions=column) and on the side (saying achievements of persons=raw) in a matrix environment 
This is what i tried

```
\[
\stackrel{\textit{Dimesions}}{%
\begin{bmatrix}
X_{11} & X_{12} & \cdots & X_{1d}\\
X_{12} & X_{22} & \cdots & X_{2d}\\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots\\
X_{n1} & X_{n2} & \cdots & X_{nd}
\end{bmatrix}
\stackrel{\textit{persons achievements}}
 }
\]
```

Yet, it does not work. what do I do? Please help urgently. I am running after time to write my Thesis!

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! The command is `\stackrel`(with an `r`). Where do you want to write the text in the second `\stackrel`?

Answer (score 1):

Here are two possibilities. I don't know if this is what you want because your specification is rather vague. If not, please insert a sketch of the desired input in your question.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{blkarray}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{multirow}
\begin{document}

\[
\begin{blockarray}{ c c c c l}
\BAmulticolumn{4}{c}{\text{Dimensions=column}} \\
\begin{block}{[ c c c c ] l}
  X_{11} & X_{12} & \cdots & X_{1d} & \multirow{4}{*}{achievements of persons=raw}\\
X_{12} & X_{22} & \cdots & X_{2d} & \\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots &\\
X_{n1} & X_{n2} & \cdots & X_{nd} & \\
\end{block}
\end{blockarray} 
\]

\[
\begin{blockarray}{ c c c c }
\BAmulticolumn{4}{c}{\text{Dimensions=column}} \\
\begin{block}{[ c c c c ] }
  X_{11} & X_{12} & \cdots & X_{1d}\\
X_{12} & X_{22} & \cdots & X_{2d} \\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots\\
X_{n1} & X_{n2} & \cdots & X_{nd} \\
\end{block}
\end{blockarray}\quad\text{achievements of persons=raw}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]